# WMI query for Win32_BaseBoard returns no results

Tags: c++, wmi

The following C++ code to retrieve the motherboard info via WMI **works on most machines, except one**:

```
IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = NULL;
hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
    bstr_t("WQL"), 
    bstr_t("Select  *  from  Win32_BaseBoard"),
    WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, 
    NULL,
    &pEnumerator);

if (FAILED(hres))
{
    // handle error, exit
}
IWbemClassObject *pclsObj = NULL;
ULONG uReturn = 0;
while (pEnumerator)
{
    HRESULT hr = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, 
        &pclsObj, &uReturn);

    if(0 == uReturn)
    {
        break;
    }
    VARIANT vtProp;

    hr = pclsObj->Get(L"Product", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
    std::wstring productNo = vtProp.bstrVal;
    // do stuff with productNo
}
```

Specifically, `pEnumerator->Next()` returns 0, and therefore `pclsObj` is left NULL.

Have you ever run into a situation where a WMI query on `Win32_BaseBoard` returns no entries?

Comment: Hi can you query any other classes and get reults? For example what does Win32_BIOS return? The thinking being that it could be an issue with WMI.

Comment: Good thinking. I'll verify with the customer on whose machine this code is running.

Comment: There is an open bug for it https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/6361

Answer (score 2):

My clean Windows XP SP3 /w .NET Framework 2.0 machine in a VirtualBox virtual machine does not return any records, as indicated by the "wmic" tool:

```
wmic:root\cli>BASEBOARD
No Instance(s) Available
```

So this appears to be a normal circumstance and not just an isolated incidence.  I would plan on the possibility that no records may appear.